# How exactly does GURPS Traveller setting material differ from OTU?

Tags: traveller, gurps, mongoose-traveller-2

I'm about to start a campaign using MgT 2e and I have tons of GT material but I've read over and over again how **Behind the Claw** (for GT) differs from **OTU**.

I'm not interested on moving rules from GURPS to MgT 2e, but information, so I just want to know which are the points where **GT** background is different from **OTU** (beyond the Dulinor issues).

Bear in mind that I intend to play the *Golden Age* (1105-) or just after the *Fifth Frontier War*.

Answer (score 8):

The TravellerRPG website has a nice summary of the various [versions of Traveller](https://wiki.travellerrpg.com/Versions_of_Traveller).  The short version is that **GURPS Traveller**:

> Set in 1116-1124 Imperial, in an alternate timeline which differs principally in that the Rebellion of 1116 never happened.

Comment: I'm not asking about differences between both versions, and I know about Rebellion as I pointed out «beyond the Dulinor issues». I want to know where they do differ beyond that.

Comment: Canonically, they don't.

Answer (score 8):

As [Jeff Zeitlin mentions in a comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90984/how-exactly-does-gurps-traveller-setting-material-differ-from-otu#comment212201_90991) on [Ghotir's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90984/how-exactly-does-gurps-traveller-setting-material-differ-from-otu/90991#90991), GURPS does not differ from the OTU beyond the "alternate timeline" issue.

In fact, since Loren Wiseman ran that line, GURPS material is generally quite good.  And when its books treat a general OTU topic, they do it so well that the material is often a very nearly GOLDEN canon source.  For example, the Sword Worlds book is as canonical as it gets.  It's nearly perfect (although it's a little dry for my tastes). If I had a canon question about the Swordies, I'd go to GURPS. Ditto for Starports.

But... sometimes the assumptions go too far for my comfort -- for example, Behind the Claw is spurious (fact, not my opinion), and Far Trader relies too heavily on Terran economics, losing sight of the game (my opinion).

Largely though you can ignore that.  If you have GURPS, and you use GURPS with an MGT2 game, you're going to be fine.

Comment: Could you provide reasoning for your claim that Behind the Claw is illegitimate information?